# What is causing strange symbol on each line Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I opened MS Word 2010 today to find that whenever I add a new line I get strange symbol.

When I press enter multiple times I get one on each line. This is very strange to me and I need to get rid of this. It happened from today itself. I checked for MS Word Replacing Characters with Line Breaks but it of no help.

How can i change this?
What may be the possible root cause?
Is it because of a crash or something?

Comment: I think Marcus' answer below is likely the cause, but in order to add details to your question, can you post a screen shot of the symbol you are seeing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are the characters pilcrows (¶)? If so, you have "show formatting" enabled, and you can disable it with the button that looks like a pilcrow. Instructions: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-or-hide-tab-marks-in-Word-84a53213-5d02-404a-b022-09cae1a3958b

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ctrl`+`*` (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`8`) to toggle this display.

Comment: To be more precise: Ctrl+Shift+8 ;-)